# Inconsistency between Task Manager Processes Tab and Performance Tab

Tags: windows-7, memory, task-manager

The Windows Task Manager, on my Windows 7 machine is consistently very inconsistent.

Specifically, the memory used by my processes (as reflected in a variety of different metrics) in the Processes tab, is always, vastly, less than the amount of memory used in the Performances tab.  See these screen shots:

[image]

and

[image]

Is there a way for me to figure out where the memory is "really" getting used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining how memory is being used to what extent is not as clear cut as many users might think. I recommend reading this excellent msdn blog article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2010/10/28/pdc10-mysteries-of-windows-memory-management-revealed-part-one.aspx

It was written by Mark Russinovich himself and explains everything in detail and much better than you could probably hope to have it answered here.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way for me to figure out where the memory is "really" getting used?"

Yes, use [RAMMap](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx) from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) to see how Windows uses the RAM.

[image: RAMMap]

[This video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-6-RAMMap) also explains how to use RAMMap.

[image]

> In this episode of Defrag Tools, Andrew and I walk you through
>   Sysinternals RAMMap. **RAMMap allows you to see how the Physical Memory
>   (RAM) on the computer is being used. You can see how much RAM there
>   is, for what purpose it is being used, and if there has been any
>   memory pressure (not enough memory). We also cover a lot of Memory
>   Management theory to understand the data in RAMMap.**